# I want to make the objects come from the right in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to make a game in which I have a ship that shoots bullets in another randon generated enemy ships. This is the code for the enemy ships. I want to make them come from the right part of the screen towards the first ship. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

```
public.AddPlayer2 = function() {
        Loader.load( "warp_ship3.js", function( ship2 ) {
            ship2.visible =  false;
            for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            public.newShip = ship2.clone();
            public.newShip.position.set((Math.random () - 0.5 ) * 100,(Math.random () - 0.5 ) * 100,(Math.random () - 0.5 ) * 100)


        public.newShip.scale.set( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );
        public.newShip.rotation.y -= Math.PI / 2;   

        public.newShip.visible = true;
        Loader.scene.add(public.newShip);

            Updater.Add({
                Update: function(){
                    public.newShip.position.y -= 2;
                }
            });

        };
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be best to use some animation technique to move ships inside the scene in real time.

I can recommend to **NOT** use jQuery `animation` for that, as many developers do. It is too slow in large amount of instances, better to use `TWEEN` library:

https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

*And*

You are not included an animation frame to your code, you will need to cycle render for animation first

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_scene